# How do i plot multiple lines from a same point of origin in a 3d plot using matlotlib in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d

Update:
I made a mistake by using coordinates of a single line to try and plot multiple lines. So the code actually works just fine. The data is the issue. Thanks for everyone who took time to check out the question.

Can someone show me how to plot multiple straight lines from the point of origin using x,y coordinates
in python in a 3d plot.
Here is what i have done, and the coordinates i'm trying to plot. The code seems to be plotting only one line,
i would like it to plot many lines using the loop.

"""

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
shapes = [
            {'shape_attribute': 
                {'name': 'line', 'x_points': [0, 8.68279650477334], 'y_points': [0, 5.400983523311377], 'z_points': [3, 3]}
            }, 
            {'shape_attribute': 
                {'name': 'line', 'x_points': [0, 8.68279650477334], 'y_points': [0, 5.400983523311377], 'z_points': [3, 3]}
            }, 
            {'shape_attribute': 
                {'name': 'line', 'x_points': [0, 8.68279650477334], 'y_points': [0, 5.400983523311377], 'z_points': [3, 3]}
            }, 
            {'shape_attribute': 
                {'name': 'line', 'x_points': [0, 8.68279650477334], 'y_points': [0, 5.400983523311377], 'z_points': [3, 3]}
            }, 
        ]

plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection = '3d')
ax.set_ylim([0, 20]) #Sets the y axis Range
ax.set_xlim([0,14]) #Sets the x axis Range
ax.set_zlim([0, 6]) #Sets the z axis Range

for shape in shapes:
    x_cor = shape['shape_attribute']['x_points']
    y_cor = shape['shape_attribute']['y_points']
    z_cor = shape['shape_attribute']['z_points']

    ax.plot3D(x_cor, y_cor, z_cor, lw=2)

ax.set_xlabel('x') #For labeling our axes
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')

plt.show()
```

Comment: the coordinates of all four `shape`s are identical, so the four lines are plotted one over the other.

Comment: @Stef i just made that realization after i posted it. Thank you for sharing the same.

Answer (score 0):

The code actually works just fine, i realized i made an error when i was preping the data for this code, as the coordinates are all for one line. Changing the data of the coordinates to reflect multiple lines, shows that the code works.
Here is the correct data for the coordinates.

```
    shapes = [
                {'shape_attribute': 
                    {'name': 'line', 'x_points': [0, 9.099814178098228], 'y_points': [0, 4.246548332911672], 'z_points': [3, 3]}
                }, 
                {'shape_attribute': 
                    {'name': 'line', 'x_points': [0, 8.984486193062779], 'y_points': [0, 4.6524460480286765], 'z_points': [3, 3]}
                }, 
                {'shape_attribute': 
                    {'name': 'line', 'x_points': [0, 8.845171322917412], 'y_points': [0, 5.0376912384632115], 'z_points': [3, 3]}
                }, 
                {'shape_attribute': 
                    {'name': 'line', 'x_points': [0, 8.68279650477334], 'y_points': [0, 5.400983523311377], 'z_points': [3, 3]}
                }, 
            ]
```

Comment: Make sure to update your question to let everyone know!

Comment: @rikyeah made the update. thanks for your input.